# Can unique ID be used to avoid duplicate entry in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Say for, if I would like one column in the table to have non equal values integer or varchar then can the unique value be used with 'insert ignore into' to avoid duplicate data entry or is it better to use some php function?.

Comment: That's pretty much the definition of a primary key. Do some research into database normalization to learn more about this.

Comment: thank you Kryten for the primary explanation but I guess I wasn't asking about it. My question was whether I can use the unique value in the database to avoid duplicate entry. If yes, should I use unique value to avoid duplicate entries or is it better using some php functions.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicate data entry, I find it easiest to use the AUTO_INCREMENT modifier on the field for a primary key.

That way you can add to the table till your hearts content without the worry of having a duplicate key. Also, try to keep SQL stuff with mySQL as much as you can.

Comment: The auto-increment column usually isn't inserted explicitly in the first place. I think he's trying to prevent duplication of a data column, like a username.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I took that one a different direction. :(

Answer (score 1):

`insert ignore` will not insert anything if there's a duplicate in the unique field. It will not raise an error either, so it depends on what you're implementing.

Answer (score 1):

Create a unique index on the column that you want to prevent duplicates. I then recomend using:

```
INSERT INTO ... 
ON DUPLICATE UPDATE columnName = columnName
```

rather than doing it in PHP, because you want to minimize the number of calls to the database. To do it in PHP means you have to do two queries: first a `SELECT` to see if the row already exists, then an `INSERT`.

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is prefereable to `INSERT IGNORE` because it doesn't prevent you from being notified of other errors. You need to specify at least one column to update; by setting the column to its current value, nothing changes.

Comment: I recommend `on duplicate key update` rather than `insert ignore` because the latter will not report on any errors, and the former will ignore only duplicate key errors.  But that is a minor quibble.

Comment: You mean `on duplicate key ignore`, right?

Comment: . . I wish that syntax were available.  Instead, just set a column equal to itself.  MySQL doesn't do an update in that case, because no data changes.

Comment: D'oh! I started googling for it, and it showed up in the completion, so I assumed it was actual syntax.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you sir, I did the unique key way and its working. If there is an entry already present, the database simply rejects the duplicate. What i wanted to know was the comparsion between using unique key or php function.